# RuleBook returns empty result

Tags: rule-engine

I am using rule Book to create rules a chain of rule as follows:

```
RuleBookBuilder.create()
      .withResultType(Boolean.class)
            .addRule(
                RuleBuilder.create()
                    .withFactType(Double.class)
                    .withResultType(Boolean.class)
                    .when(facts -> facts.get("amount_gt").getValue() > new Double(600))
                    .then((facts, result) -> {
                      result.setValue(true);
                      System.out.println(result.getValue()); //1st print statement
                    })
                    .addRule()
                    ....
                    .build())

NameValueReferableMap facts = new FactMap();
facts.setValue("amount_gt", new Double(700));

rule.run(facts);
System.out.println(rule.getResult()); //2nd print statement
```

The fist print statement prints true (as excepted), but the 2nd statement gives Optional.empty 
Can some one tell me what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to chain the rules and the return of the outer rule you are not showing.
If you are trying to access the return on an inner rule, then you need to similarly chain the get() calls.

I would try to "unchain" the rules and see what that yields.